# How can you access shared network folders with cmd.exe on Windows 7/10 when the folder name contains a space?

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line

I have no problem accessing shared folders on other computers on the network when the folder name consists of a single word, but I have not yet found a way to access folders whose name contains a space.  (the old usage of replacing "my documents" with "mydocu~1" does not work on the network, nor does simply deleting the space, or leaving it in).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the file or folder path should help here.

dir "x:\folder1\folder name with spaces"